# Duality Theory Question (Exericse 4.34 in Bertsimas)

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

Suppose $P = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : Ax \ge b\} \ne \emptyset$ is a polyhedron where all inequalities are elementwise for the vectors $Ax$ and $b$ and suppose $0 \not \in P$.  I want to find a separating hyperplane using duality theory, but I'm confused about the following approach:  Consider the linear program (P) given by \begin{align} \min \quad & 0'x \\ \text{subject to: } & Ax \ge b \\ & x =0\end{align}  Its dual (D) is (?, I'm not sure here) \begin{align} \max \quad & b'y \\ \text{subject to: } & y \ge 0 \\ & A'y = 0\end{align}  The second constraint in the dual is perhaps fishy.  Anyways, (D) must be unbounded since it is feasible (take $y = 0$) and (P) is infeasible by assumption.  Hence, there exists $y$ with $b'y > 0$, but then this is a contradiction since Farkas's lemma implies only one of the two alternate systems $Ax \ge b$ and $b'y > 0$, $y \ge 0$, $A'y = 0$ has a solution.  So I'm convinced that I'm quoting the dual incorrectly here, but I don't understand how (see page 142 of Bertsimas - Introduction to Linear Optimization for a definition of the dual).  Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: I would write $x=0$ as $Ix=0$, where I is the identity matrix. Then at the dual you have something like $A^{'}y_1+Iy_2=0$. Of course it is doubtful, if this problem makes any sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the following table to get a correct dualisation.[image: Duality Rules]

Therefore, your dual corresponds to the primal without $x=0$. So the primal becomes feasible, with the Farkas' Lemma being verified. I suggest you use the following trick as you may need more dual variables to solve your problem:

$\begin{array}{rrclcl}
\displaystyle \min_{x} & {{0^T[x\,-x]}}&&\qquad&\displaystyle \max_{y}&{{[b\,-b]^T[y_1\,y_2]}}\\
\textrm{s.t.} & Ax\geq b&\implies&\qquad&\textrm{s.t.} & A^Ty_1\leq0\\
\quad & A(-x)\leq -b&\qquad&\qquad&\qquad& A^Ty_2\leq0\\\
 &x\geq0&\qquad&\qquad& &y_1\geq 0  \\
 &-x\geq0&\qquad&\qquad& &y_2\leq 0  \\
\end{array}$